# How to have picture uploaded from facebook-graph-api showing directly in same way as from web browser?

Tags: image, facebook-graph-api, upload

You can see the difference from below picture. Target is to show picture without downloading..

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What are you asking? Your question isn't explained very well

Answer (score 0):

In your example, one of those is a treated as a document, the other is a picture. Probably something wrong happened with the file or your upload. With pictures, a preview will automatically be shown. With documents, they will not.